# How to create new packages in an Android project

Tags: java, android

I have too many activities in my Android app project and I'd like to manage them using packages.

How can I do it?

Comment: just right click on your project name and select Project>>new>>package and give the package name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse:

Right click on the project and choose new => "package".

[image: Eclipse: Creating new package]

[image: Eclipse: New package wizard]

You may need to update your references to other classes once reorganised. I find ctrl+shift+o can help you there too.

Comment: I realise the package name doesn't meet conventions etc - it was just to show the screens.

Answer (score 2):

in android you have a package name like com.your.package.name. this is your master package. you must create other packages as asub-package of this.

To use this packages in manifest use: ".subpackage.Activity" android os will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Right click to src folder in your project->New->package.write the name of the package there->Finish.you will see the package what you named under src folder of your project.Add class files into that package.While using the clsses of different packages you have to import the classes as they belong to other package and you also have to declare it in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

I Enjoy creating Package in separate Way.

If you are working in Eclipse Just mention the desire package name at top.

Eclipse will automatically do trick for you.

[image]