# How to make package inside master package in Android project using Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package

I read here - [How to create new packages in an Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391918/how-to-create-new-packages-in-an-android-project) how to make a package, but I need to make a package inside master package com.example.me.

Every time I try to make new package there, it makes package in src folder, not in com.example.me package.

I mean something like this:

```
<com.example.me
    <package1
        <Class1
    <package2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create a package inside the com.example.me , you need to write the new package name as com.example.me.Package1 while adding the New Package

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did it, but package is still appearing as a "separate" and I can see question mark on it

Comment: Does your newly created package read com.example.me.package1? if so, even it shows as a separate package, it will be created under the existing package structure. i.e., under com.example.me
you can check by exploring its folder structure on your machine.